# How do you know whether a differential equation has a solution that is constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I recently encountered the following problem in a Calculus textbook:

Prove that the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2y+1$$
has a solution that is constant.

I determined that $$y = \frac{e^{x+c}-1}{2}.$$

What should I do from here? Is there a general way of knowing whether a differential equation has a solution that is constant?

Comment: Try with $y=C$ in this one. You will get $0=2C+1$, so $C$ must be $-1/2$. Does it work? By the way, I think your solution should be $y=Ce^{2x}-1/2$. Written like that, your constant solution $y=-1/2$ is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y' = F(y)$ be a differential equation. If it has a constant solution $y=c$, then $y' = 0$, and so $c$ must satisfy $F(c) = c' = 0$. Hence, $y=c$ is a contant solution of $y'=F(y)$ iff $F(c)=0$.

If $F(c)=0$ has no solutions, e.g. if $F(y) = y^2+1$, then the differential equation has no constant solutions. In this case, we get $y' = y^2+1$ which has general solution $y(x) = \tan(x+C)$, and none of these are constant.